# Bitwise operations between a bigger and a smaller number

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

```
int main(){
 long a = -246;
 int b = -5;
 int c = a | b;
}
```

Above code will have this bit pattern:

```
a = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001010
b =                                 11111111111111111111111111111011
c =                                 11111111111111111111111111111011
```

So if operating between two different bit counts, the smaller bit count is chosen and the 
remaining bits are discarded? I.e `0s` don't get put to the left of `b` to match the bit-count of `a`?

Comment: I think `b` will be promoted to `long` then the ORing will take place and the result will be cast to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer promotion takes place here

```
long a = -246;
int b = -5;
int c = (int)( a | ((long)b) ); // <- equivalent to int c = a | b;
```

Note: as @Fredrik mentioned, if long is wider than int.

Comment: So i'm guessing, when promoted, if the original value is positive, 0's get put to its left and it's its negative 1's get put in place?

Comment: @Nic never do bit operations on signed numbers, use unsigned.

Comment: @Nic Yes. When upcasting on two's complement architectures, signed integers get sign extended (by 0 if positive, by 1 if negative) and unsigned integers get zero extended (always by 0).

Comment: @Nic because integer promotion can cause errors who are hard to see when you are doing bit operations with signed.